# Java Money - currency conversion rate on specific date

Tags: java, currency, java-money

I'm trying to get exchange rate on specific date between EUR and USD. The issue is I'm allways getting exchange dare for date: `LocalDate{year=2016, month=1, dayOfMonth=8}` and it does not matter if I specify date in query.

Here are my maven dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.money</groupId>
            <artifactId>money-api-bp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javamoney</groupId>
            <artifactId>moneta-bp</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Source code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConversionQuery query = ConversionQueryBuilder.of()
                .setProviderName("ECB")
                .setBaseCurrency(Monetary.getCurrency("EUR"))
                .setTermCurrency(Monetary.getCurrency("USD"))
                .set(LocalDate.class, LocalDate.of(2017, Month.SEPTEMBER, 10))
                .build();
        final ExchangeRateProvider provider = getExchangeRateProvider(query);
        final ExchangeRate rate1 = provider.getExchangeRate(query);
        System.out.println(rate1);

        ExchangeRateProvider ecbExchangeRateProvider = MonetaryConversions.getExchangeRateProvider("ECB");
        ExchangeRate rate = ecbExchangeRateProvider.getExchangeRate("EUR", "USD");
        System.out.println(rate);

    }
}
```

And the output from sout:

```
sep. 11, 2017 9:58:29 AM org.javamoney.moneta.internal.convert.ECBAbstractRateProvider newDataLoaded
INFO: Loaded ECBCurrentRateProvider exchange rates for days:1
sep. 11, 2017 9:58:30 AM org.javamoney.moneta.internal.convert.ECBAbstractRateProvider newDataLoaded
INFO: Loaded ECBHistoric90RateProvider exchange rates for days:63
ExchangeRate [base=EUR, factor=1.0861, conversionContext=ConversionContext (
{provider=ECB, rateTypes=[DEFERRED], providerDescription=European Central Bank, days=1, org.javamoney.moneta.internal.convert.LocalDate=LocalDate{year=2016, month=1, dayOfMonth=8}, javax.money.convert.RateType=HISTORIC})]
ExchangeRate [base=EUR, factor=1.0861, conversionContext=ConversionContext (
{provider=ECB, rateTypes=[DEFERRED], providerDescription=European Central Bank, days=1, org.javamoney.moneta.internal.convert.LocalDate=LocalDate{year=2016, month=1, dayOfMonth=8}, javax.money.convert.RateType=HISTORIC})]
ExchangeRate [base=USD, factor=0.9207255317189946, conversionContext=ConversionContext (
{provider=ECB, rateTypes=[DEFERRED], providerDescription=European Central Bank, days=1, org.javamoney.moneta.internal.convert.LocalDate=LocalDate{year=2016, month=1, dayOfMonth=8}, javax.money.convert.RateType=HISTORIC})]
sep. 11, 2017 9:58:35 AM org.javamoney.moneta.internal.convert.ECBAbstractRateProvider newDataLoaded
INFO: Loaded ECBHistoricRateProvider exchange rates for days:4358
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which `LocalDate` class are you importing?

Comment: The `LocaleDate` seems like the one from JDK8. Why are you using the backport library (`-bp`) which is explicitly compiled with JDK7?

Comment: I'm using java.time.LocalDate as an import. Because if i'm using dependency on money-api without bp I get null as an result. And wrong import does not explain why I get some old day in second example. And if i change to: .set(org.javamoney.moneta.internal.convert.LocalDate.class, org.javamoney.moneta.internal.convert.LocalDate.from(Calendar.getInstance())) i get the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This API is currently obscure. If you get:

```
ConversionQueryBuilder.of().setTermCurrency("EUR").
        set(LocalDate.class, LocalDate.of(2018, 1, 1)).build()
MonetaryConversions.getConversion(conversionQuery)
```

It will use following method:

```
default CurrencyConversion getConversion(ConversionQuery conversionQuery) {
    return getExchangeRateProvider(conversionQuery).getCurrencyConversion(
            Objects.requireNonNull(conversionQuery.getCurrency(), "Terminating Currency is required.")
    );
}
```

As you can see, the `conversionQuery` is used to get the provider, **not** the conversion object itself. It's always returned for query with only currency set, never with date.

To make it working use:

```
MonetaryConversions.getExchangeRateProvider().getCurrencyConversion(conversionQuery)
```

I believe it should work consistently for all invocations.